# php login script failing

Tags: php, authentication

I have a login script that was working fine - I exported the db and scripts over locally after making it work online (backward I know) but since the port both online and offline failing to login my dummy account - it will register a new user and salt the passwords fine but when logging in it directs you to the failed page? Not sure why and unsure where it is failing?

Heres my code:

Login form:

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'in';
} else {
    $logged = 'out';
}
?>
```

The process script:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

An included function script:

```
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';

function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}



function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
        FROM members
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
    // Get timestamp of current time 
    $now = time();

    // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
    $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time 
                             FROM login_attempts <code><pre>
                             WHERE user_id = ? 
                            AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

        // Execute the prepared query. 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // If there have been more than 5 failed logins 
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                        $_SESSION['username'], 
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
                                      FROM members 
                                      WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                    // Logged In!!!! 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
}

function esc_url($url) {

    if ('' == $url) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = (string) $url;

    $count = 1;
    while ($count) {
        $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
    }

    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

    $url = htmlentities($url);

    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

    if ($url[0] !== '/') {
        // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        return '';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

I have tried backtracking but nothing I am changing is working and I feel like I maybe doing more harm than good!

Comment: The word `SECURE` in `$secure = SECURE;` isn't being treated as a string. Is there a constant defined for it?

Comment: Does the password really get hashed twice? `$password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.` - later in the `login` function, you hash it again.

Comment: And what is `<code><pre>` doing in `FROM login_attempts <code><pre>` is it an SO-related thing?

Comment: You could try poping up alert box in each of the right path into your if-else logics.

Answer (score 0):

The design pattern for PHP client authentication has been shown in almost every book on the subject over the last ten years.  I have a deliberately over-simplified and procedural version of it available in this article.  You might try comparing your script to the super-simple version.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_2391-PHP-login-logout-and-easy-access-control.html

HTH, ~Ray

Comment: From a quick look, your *super simple* script has SQL injection, uses deprecated `mysql_`,.. no insult, but this is not a solution. For example this query `"SELECT uid FROM EE_userTable WHERE uuk = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['uuk'])."' LIMIT 1` ... it looks *super simple* to circumvent authentication. `mysql_real_escape_string` does not prevent data manipulation.

Comment: Yes, Dan.  It's a very old answer to a very old question.  If you can guess a 32-byte pseudorandom character string and send it in a cookie, you can, in fact, circumvent authentication.  In practice using almost exactly this script, that has never happened.  You might also note that the article specifically called out the use of the MySQL extension as obsolete.  It also included a discussion of hashing passwords, but no examples.  As I said, it's a design pattern, not a custom-built solution.  If you would like to join Experts-Exchange and post your comments in the article, you're welcome!